# Implementing phone communication with my C# application

Tags: c#, android, server, client, communication

I want to have the app i am creating to communicate with my personal android device. As in, my application will be monitoring something on my server, and when something changes it needs to somehow send an option to act or ignore to my phone, and my personal reply (Yes/No) should be send back to the server.

I don't mind any specific protocols. Anything which does not require an app running actively on my phone would be nice, but i am not that great with android native development so if it can be done it should be relatively simply to achieve.

My own idea would be to actually implement Email somehow. So my phone could get an email on my google account (which in turn creates a notification), to which i would send a reply email with my reply. Which in turn will be read out on my server.

The bad part is that i would have to actually open gmail and type out a short message to send back as a reply. So anything easier then that would be a great thing.

I have seen newer android 6 apps use custom buttons in notifications in order for the app to act on, but i have no clue how hard those are to implement and rig to my reply.

Please note that this application is probably nothing that will go public. So i am not going to bother to worry about load or efficiency in the end of it. Since it will be just me and my server.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. The most convenient/easy-to-use method will be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think...u can use xml-rpc " http://xmlrpc.scripting.com " for communicating with your server and android app.

I used it in my personal project and found iI to be useful.In my case,I used wordpress as framework so any new updates in my server is notified by this protocol.

Comment: That actually looks a lot like what i want to achieve. It would still require me to figure out the android part to get a notification on my end, but it will probably do.